# Umongo on Windows can't list collections

Tags: mongodb

I'm using monodb on Windows 10,and today,I tried umongo as a  graphical management interface.However,after I conected mongodb and Umongo,it just show dbs,when I double-clicked any db name,it didn't show collections as the offical docutment said.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt8WX.jpg)

Comment: give a try to Rockmongo

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with umongo 1.6.2 and windows 10.

Unfortunately Umongo is not supported anymore so I dont think this problem will be solved anytime soon:
http://mongodb-tools.com/tool/umongo/

I ended up downloading Robomongo, it is minimalistic and the first impression is good.

Go to http://mongodb-tools.com/ and look for Robomongo. If you don't like it you can always look for some other tools.